# Client can receive events but can't emit

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I have my client set up like this:

```
var socket = io();

socket.on('thing', function(socket){
        console.log('A user connected: ' + socket.data);
});

function sendThing(){
    var data = document.getElementById('myInput').value;
    console.log(data)
    socket.emit('message', { message: data });
}
```

I can receive events just fine, I have my server emit an event and it logs out fine:

```
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  io.emit('thing', { data: 'thisisathing' });
});
```

Edit: my on.message function:

```
io.on('message', (socket) => {
    console.log(socket.message);
});
```

But my server never receives a message because the emit on the client side does not fire. Socket exists and I get no errors.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Do you have a event handler setup on the server to receive messages?

Comment: I do, I have edited my question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try nesting your listener within your connection function like:

```
io.on('connection', (socket) => {

    socket.on('message', (socket) => {
        console.log(socket.message);
    });

});
```

as described in the [docs](http://socket.io/docs/)

Comment: I also listen for 'connection' too, I have amended my question to include the function

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to listen to `message` inside the connection :

```
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  socket.emit('thing', { data: 'thisisathing' });
  socket.on('message', (data) => {
    console.log(data.message);
  });
});
```

Comment: I've not had to do this when using socket.io before, anyhow it didn't work

edit: works when I call emit on the passed 'socket'

Comment: Did you look at the docs and also try the syntax in my answer (slightly different)

Comment: In fact you anwsered correctly before me. So, JmJ feel free to mark @Maxwell Lasky answer to correct.

Comment: haha no worries hopefully @JmJ makes that change to prevent others any confusion